Compare dynamic results on Parameters in Tableau
I am working on one tricky scenario with my dataset due to a requirement. I tried using Parameters and Multiple If Conditions however it does not seems to give a right output. I have attached the workbook.
My requirement is as follows.

Input the Material and CRM ID through parameters.
Let's say user enters material as 3543-2 (Highlighted in yellow in attached image) and CRMID as KK-0432 (Yellow)
Since both don't match each other, in this case the CRMID's (KK-0432) CBT Team should be considered which is "ATR Airlines Americas". (Green)
Based on the CBT Team which is "ATR Airlines Americas" it should map to the Material which user gave initially 3543-2 and print the path2 price (Blue). else print blank

I tried using through below expression, can some one help me here?
My final output should be if user enters Material as 3542-2 and CRMID as KK-0432 then it should give me 54.9 (Path2 price) due to mapping of CBT Team as explain in above.

IF [Material P] = [Material #] AND [CRM ID P] = [Crm Id] THEN 
  [Path 1 Price]
ELSEIF [Material P] = [Material #] AND [CRM ID P] != [Crm Id] THEN 
  IF [Material P] = [Material #] AND [CRM ID P] = [CBT Team1] THEN 
    [Path 2 Price]
  ELSE 
    [Path 3 Price]
  END
END


[CBT Team1]
CASE [CRM ID P]
WHEN '1-1632' THEN 'ATR Airlines Americas'
WHEN 'A-010AAAQ' THEN 'ATR Airlines Americas'
WHEN '' THEN ''
WHEN '' THEN 'ATR Airlines Americas'
WHEN 'KK-0432' THEN 'ATR Airlines Americas'
END

